# Using Windows installers created in SCCM on a custom boot menu

Tags: windows, boot

I'm wanting to place several Windows Installers on an external HD and have a custom boot menu on it so one of those builds can be selected.

Each of these are Windows 7 builds which have been created in SCCM and can be either be exported from SCCM as an ISO or as build media.

I'm aware that there are several guides and applications on the web about how to do this but none mention Windows Installers or if they do they mention not to try it with Windows Installers. This is where the problem comes in as I'm not trying to do this with standard Isos.

Can anyone advise on if this can be achieved and if so how.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how this is related to security?

Comment: It isn't my lack of familarity with the site meant I posted this in the wrong area.

Comment: No worries. It will probably be migrated to the correct site eventually.